# c++: #define a new skipping keyword / make compile ignore code

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is there a way to do something like

```
#define commentstart /*
```

or

```
#define ignore #ifdef 0
```

?
I basically want to make the compiler ignore any code written between two keywords, that I define myself. Any suggestion?

**example**

```
COMMENTSTART
whatever I write here will not be taken as code
COMMENTEND
```

Comment: Sorry, no, the features that would make this possible were deliberately left out of the C preprocessor.  I'm betting this is a duplicate, but I don't have the link to hand.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I think he has job security issues and wants to make the code unreadable

Comment: Hey guys. There is nothing wrong in this question. The guy is just asking for advice.

Comment: as stated under kirills answer: I want to use this for introducing my own cpp code, that can be read by my own parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C/C++ does not allow preprocessor statements inside macro definitions. The same story for comments. Comments cannot cross macro boundaries.

I do not think that your idea with COMMENTSTART/COMMENTEND is a good idea. What is the point in introducing something new when something well known and working is already existing? If you will write

```
#if 0
   ..............
#endif
```

everybody will immediately understand what does that mean. Try this several times and after a while you will be comfortable with this.

Comment: technically: make cpp files parsable by an extra code parser, but keep usual code layout.